# How to get mulitple customer id based on checking checkbox?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to get multiple customer id based on checking checkbox And clicking of button ??

My Html File:-

```
 <td><input type="checkbox" name="option" value="{{item.customerid}} " required ></td>
 <input type="button" value="Transfer" (click)="getclickedevent($event)">
```

My Javascript file:-

```
 getclickedevent(event) {

  let id  = $("input:checkbox[name=option]:checked").val();

    console.log("The Required checkbox checked is "+ id)

  }
```

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356679/1823841) here to show the issue.

Comment: Value is dynamic here ...but when i select multiple checkbox and try to get all the values ..it just show only one value ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get value for multiple elements with same `name` attribute then you need to loop through them using [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method like:

```
$("input:checkbox[name=option]:checked").each(function( index ) {
  let id  = $(this).val();
  console.log(index + ": " + "The Required checkbox checked is " + id)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 let ids  = $("input:checkbox[name=option]:checked");

 for(var i=0; i<ids.length; i++){
    console.log(ids[i].value);
  };
```

I hope it helps...

Keep rocking....